# IL Trimmer Error in .NET MAUI Application

Tags: c#, .net, maui

When try to build my .net maui application in release mode. I am getting error like
Severity code   description project file    line    suppression state error il1012  il trimmer has encountered an unexpected error. Please report the issue at https://github.com/dotnet/linker/issues
Optimising assembly for size failed.
And sometimes " fatal error in il linker out of memory ". But my ram is very fine occupancy at max 65%.
So, what's happening?

[Image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXEeW.jpg)

But in Debug mode it's working perfectly.

I tried deleting obj and bin folder, clean solution, cleaned project, tried to build the project no success.

Comment: You need to edit the question to include **the exact error message**, not your own words.

Comment: and turn off your caps lock

Comment: Edited the question attached a screenshot please check

Comment: Don't use screenshots for error messages, please. Paste them as text instead.

Comment: I have pasted from what i got in error list. Is there another way to copy the error details other than error list window?

Comment: You can copy the errors as text

Comment: I have done that after editing the question. For reference i even attached the screenshot of that error list.so it's even better to understand i think. It's not like i have only posted the image and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had this issue. It was the page file that needs to be increased and got that fixed in my case..You can check if you page file size is set to automatic or custom.

Comment: where can i check this page file size in my .net maui blazor project

Comment: What is a good value for the page file with respect to MAUI? @TechOverflow